# What are the Units of Flux and How do They Relate to Their Physical Meaning

Tags: multivariable-calculus, dimensional-analysis

While taking Calculus III, which included some vector calculus, we defined the flux of a vector field $\mathbf{F} \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ through a surface $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ as $$\iint_S \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, d\sigma.$$ We were told that if we thought of $\mathbf{F}$ as the vector field defining how a fluid moves through space, the flux calculates the rate at which this fluid flows through $S$. Intuitively then, wouldn't the "units" then be something along the line of $$\frac{``\text{quantity"}}{\text{time}}.$$ So something like "The flux through $S$ is the amount of quantity that moves through it, as defined by $\mathbf{F}$, each unit of time."

However, looking at the integral, the units seem to be different. They seem to be $$\frac{``\text{quantity"}}{\text{time}} \cdot \text{area}.$$ I really don't understand what the extra area quantity is doing. If we want to know the rate at which a quantity moves through $S$, doesn't this imply that $$\frac{``\text{quantity"}}{\text{time}}$$ measures the rate at which a quantity moves through $S$ *per unit of area*? As if there lies in a secret dimension? Multiplying by area then gives the total flux for that small surface.

Take for example finding the flux of an electric field through a surface. The units of electric flux is $$\frac{\text{N}}{\text{C}} \cdot \text{m}^2.$$ (More surprising here is that there isn't a notion of time; but I suppose that's because previously, we thought of the vector field defining motion?) What is the extra $\text{m}^2$ factor representing? Why wouldn't the total amount of "electric field going through a surface" simply be in the units of the electric field ($\text{N}/\text{C}$) rather than including an extra "area" dimension?

Comment: Flux is typically not a rate, so there's usually no time involved.  The unit of flux is typically "quantity times area."

Comment: If you think about fluid flow, the velocity might be meters per second. When you integrate you get a factor of meters squared, leading to cubic meters per second overall. I.e., what volume of fluid flows through the whole surface per second

Comment: The thing you integrate is not just "quantity/time", it's "quantity/(time * area)", which is why you don't have area after integration.

Comment: In the case of electric flux however, which is a consequence of the double integral I’ve written, you do have an area dimension left.

Comment: @JesseMadnick I'm struggling to see how that's synonymous to "how much of $\mathbf{F}$ goes through $S$", which is my understanding of what flux is. Is there a mistake in my way of thinking?

Comment: @BoredComedy: Here's a simple case: Consider $\mathbf{F}(x,y,z) = (a, b, c)$, where $a,b,c$ are fixed constants, and $S$ is a region in the $xy$-plane, oriented upwards.  Then the flux $\Phi = \iint_S \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n}\,dS = c\,\text{Area}(S)$.  So, the flux depends **both** on the part of $\mathbf{F}$ that is normal to $S$, as well as the area of $S$ itself.

Comment: @JesseMadnick I see. Thanks, that was helpful! Also, just to confirm, would it be correct to describe the units of flux density to be flux over volume for the 3-dimensional case? So flux density is the derivative of flux with respect to volume?

Answer (score 0):

The thing you integrate is actually flux density, which is a vector (or, rather, a 1-form) and has (if you ignore the fact that it is a linear form and not scalar) units
$$\frac{\text{quantity}}{\text{time} \cdot \text{area}}$$
It measures the amount of quantity transported through a unit area oriented in a given direction per unit time. So when you integrate it, you sum over elementary oriented areas (act with this 1-form on the normal vector of element of the surface), and the area cancels out, leaving you with $\text{quantity}/\text{time}$.

Comment: That’s what I was telling myself until I realized that flux density is $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}$, and to find the flux through a surface you’d need a triple integral over the closed volume. That is, if $S$ was a closed surface itself. You seem to imply the 2D case of Green’s Theorem, where we integrate over a closed region? In this case, the double integrate, based on what I understand, does cancel out the “area” dimension, leaving us only with quantity. However, I don’t see how the line integral of $\mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, ds$ over the boundary cancels out the length dimension.